# Efficient way to store tuples in the datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

If I have a pair of floats, is it any more efficient (computationally or storage-wise) to store them as a `GeoPtProperty` than it would be pickle the tuple and store it as a `BlobProperty`?

If `GeoPt` is doing something more clever to keep multiple values in a single property, can it be leveraged for arbitrary data? Can I store the tuple `("Johnny", 5)` in a single entity property in a similarly efficient manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some empirical answers:

`GeoPtProperty` uses 31B of storage space.

Using `BlobProperty` varies based on what exactly you store:

- `struct.pack('>2f', lat, lon)` => 21B.
- Using pickle (v2) to packe a 2-tuple containing floats => 37B.
- Using pickle (v0) to packe a 2-tuple containing floats => about 30B-32B (v0 uses a variable-length ascii encoding for floats).

In short, it doesn't look like `GeoPt` is doing anything particularly clever.  If you are going to be storing a lot of these, then you could use `struct` to pack your floats.  Packing and unpacking them with `struct` will probably be unnoticeably different from the CPU cost associated with serializing/deserializing `GeoPt`.

If you plan on storing *lots* of floats per entity and space is really important, then you might consider leveraging the `CompressedBlobProperty` in [aetycoon](http://github.com/Arachnid/aetycoon/blob/master/__init__.py#L624).

*Disclaimer*: This is the minimum space required.  Actual space will be slightly larger per property based on the length of the property's name.  The model itself also adds overhead (for its name and key).

Comment: For fun ... `GeoPt` seems to be stored as a "point" value.  Specifically, the data itself seems to take 18B - two 1-byte integers and two 8-byte doubles (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/entity_pb.py#215)) for a total of 18 bytes.  The `struct` solution packs each float into 4 bytes for a total of 8-bytes.  Both therefore have 13B of "overhead" from the rest of the property info from my tests above (the overhead is expected to be the same since the only thing differing between my tests is the property type).

Comment: Your analysis doesn't take into account CPU time - pickling and depickling is typically very computationally expensive. Using a struct is a good idea, though. The newly added ArrayProperty in AETycoon is also worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

GeoPt itself is limited to (-90 - 90, -180 - 180); it can't be used to store any data that won't fit this model.

However, a custom tuple property shouldn't be too difficult to create yourself; take a look at how SetProperty and ArrayProperty are designed in [aetycoon](http://github.com/Arachnid/aetycoon).