# Efficient storage of tuples

Tags: python, database, serialization

I already know of the existence of this subject: [Efficient way to store tuples in the datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010375/efficient-way-to-store-tuples-in-the-datastore) but it does not quite cover the question in my opinion.

This is my case: I have a some key->value dictionary where keys are strings (not important), and values are tuples of floats.

I want to create a database where "value" becomes an index, and an index can be associated with more than one key (string here).

The goal here is to convert the values into binary arrays to allow for O(1) search in a database. The values don't have to be stored *exactly*, I can truncate the floats to gain efficiency.

Thus my question has three points: what would you do in term of

- Truncation process
- Encryption process
- Storage in the database

so that the overall be as efficient (O(1) time, not too space-consuming) as possible.

Comment: Why is encryption a goal? Do you actually need to encryption your database?

Comment: example of what you have and what you want it to be would be excellent.

Comment: How much truncation would you allow? Because in your model, too much truncation can lead to only few values, each associated with many keys. 

Also, do you need to keep keys and values in this order? Why don't you have an opposite map from values -> keys?

Comment: EricUrban: "encryption" is an abuse term for serialization, I want to perform Hamming distance search so I need a bit conversion.

sihrc: I have tuples and strings, I want to convert a tuple to a single bit word and use it as a key for multiple strings.

Yasser: I'm not really worried about loss of information, as I want to study how loss of information affects performance of the search. 

Typically, say you have a string associated with a lot of decoupled data, represented as many tuples. My goal is to determine, knowing the tuples, which string is the most probable association.

Comment: If you're really using a database that stores to disk, just use sqlite3 - great performance on searches, efficient data storage, and has support for encryption via third party addons like http://sqlcipher.net/. I 'get' why you would want to write your own, but if it has to be written to disk or flash, sqlite3 with a little bit of work is going to be a thousand times more reliable than hand-rolled solutions. If I'm misunderstanding your use of the word 'database', feel free to ignore this input. Also, FWIW, Python treats all floats as _doubles_, so efficiency is in the eye of the beholder.